# How to reshape a (r, c, 1) matrix to (r, c)

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, deep-learning, reshape

Given a matrix of shape (r, c, 1) like the below:

```
[[[1], [4], [5]],
 [[1], [7], [6]],
 ...
 [[9], [2], [8]]]
```

I would like it to be reshaped as (r, c):

```
[[1, 4, 5],
 [1, 7, 6],
 [9, 2, 8]]
```

Comment: did you try data.reshape((r, c)) ?

Comment: Yet another way: `arr[:,:,0]`, indexing on the size 1 dimension.

Comment: @hpaulj Or even better `arr[..., 0]`

Comment: I tried data.reshape((r, c)) but it didnt help

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
import numpy as np

np.squeeze(my_matrix)
```

This returns a reshaped "view" of `my_matrix` after removing any unit-length dimensions.

**Alternatives:**

1. `my_matrix.reshape(r,c)` also returns a re-shaped view
2. `my_matrix.shape = (r,c)` alters the shape of `my_matrix` "in-place"